# Git remove root commit

Tags: git, commit

I can't do a lot of things with git and I want to remove a commit from my repo, because I uploaded wrong stuff.

I used `git revert <the_commit>` but since the commit is root and I can't remove it.
fatal: Cannot revert a root commit

What to do in that case ?

Please don't give me links to other topics here, I read them and I don't understand what to do, I need some basic example about removing some commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For removing a root commit, you simply have to remove all branches (and tags) from which it is reachable.

This can be done with `git branch -D branch-name`. (You will have to first check out another branch which does not refer to this root commit, since you can't remove the current branch, I think.)

If you want to retain other commits on this branch and only remove the root, `git filter-branch` is better, see the answer from Greg.

Answer (score 29):

You can do this using [git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). First, identify the commit ID at the root that you want to remove. I'll represent that with `<the_commit>`. Then, run `git filter-branch` using `--parent-filter` and a `sed` command that snips off that parent:

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter "sed 's/-p <the_commit>//'" HEAD
```

Here's a transcript of an example I just tried:

```
$ git log
commit 7e1ba37b51fc2cc6289cf66367c9aedc74c664a8
Author: Greg Hewgill <greg@example.com>
Date:   Fri May 27 20:54:27 2011 +1200

    three

commit a8a410d2361824cbd518a48225e9402a691be93f
Author: Greg Hewgill <greg@example.com>
Date:   Fri May 27 20:54:17 2011 +1200

    two

commit 3171d512d98f6bc5f3c2469312930c0d32d3aa07
Author: Greg Hewgill <greg@example.com>
Date:   Fri May 27 20:54:00 2011 +1200

    one
$ git filter-branch --parent-filter "sed 's/-p 3171d512d98f6bc5f3c2469312930c0d32d3aa07//'" HEAD
Rewrite 7e1ba37b51fc2cc6289cf66367c9aedc74c664a8 (3/3)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
$ git log
commit 489ec1ee20e0dd20cd835ceebf157f628cd75a44
Author: Greg Hewgill <greg@example.com>
Date:   Fri May 27 20:54:27 2011 +1200

    three

commit a6f5ee410c9ea4fca6fbff265149b7fc555241eb
Author: Greg Hewgill <greg@example.com>
Date:   Fri May 27 20:54:17 2011 +1200

    two
$
```

Comment: This is an extremely helpful answer and I have verified that it works. Thanks!